# Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, nginx

I am trying to install/update things ( php7.0-soap for example) but this message keep appearing.

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-http-echo : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-http-geoip : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-http-image-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-mail : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
     libnginx-mod-stream : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.1-3+xenial2) but 1.10.1-0+xenial0 is to be installed
```

apt-update is also blocked by this one. For now I really need soap, in the future maybe more things. Is there a way to fix this without (or with minimum) impact on the running nginx server, which is usually serving 300-600 users at a time.

We are using : Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

```
    lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Release:        16.04
    Codename:       xenial
```

**UPDATE Jan 1st 2017:**

Using -f in "apt-get dist-upgrade" or "apt-get install" as suggested by **@Thomas Ward** did make some progress. But I am stuck at :

```
    Unpacking nginx-common (1.10.1-3+xenial2) over (1.10.1-0+xenial0) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.10.1-3+xen                                 ial2_all.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/etc/logrotate.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.                                 11.3-1~xenial
    Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.10.1-3+xenial2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking nginx-full (1.10.1-3+xenial2) over (1.10.1-0+xenial0) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.10.1-3+xenia                                 l2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.11.3-1~                                 xenial
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Preparing to unpack .../init-system-helpers_1.29ubuntu4_all.deb ...
    Unpacking init-system-helpers (1.29ubuntu4) over (1.29ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.10.1-3+xenial2_all.deb
     /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.10.1-3+xenial2_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I understand what it is saying but have no clue what to do..

Comment: Run a full `apt-get update` and then `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  Your system wants all the *new* nginx versions and dependencies as a result of the NGINX PPAs resyncing with Debian, pulling in different dependency sets.  Did you try `apt-get install -f` at all either?  That sometimes helps.

Comment: @ThomasWard : thanks, it did progress but give error, could you let me know what I should do next

Answer (score 3):

I ended up purge  those libnginx-mod-... then purged nginxfull and nginx-common.

Then "dpkg -i --force-overwrite" any file that is in the way. Finally restore nginx config files in /etc/nginx (which I backed up earlier of course).

The server was down for like 5-10 mins... but things are done. Thanks Thomas for helping out

Comment: Glad I could help.  These steps you indicated *actually* are the same steps I detailed in [a blog post of mine on the subject of mixing and matching the upstream nginx repositories and the NGINX PPA I help maintain](http://dark-net.net/?p=80).  Glad you solved it though!  :)

Comment: `apt purge 'libnginx-mod-*'` to purge everything. I thought this would take down my website but apparently not.

Comment: @mpen : good to know, hope it helps ppl in the future